# Set all the values from a Forloop

Tags: python, wxpython

I need to set all the values into a textctrl but it just set the las value

```
lstA = list(CONTENIDO)
for RT in lstA:
    print RT
    self.loggerb.SetValue(RT)
```

Comment: of coarse... each one sets it... but its so fast you dont see any but the last one...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

perhaps you want

```
self.loggerb.SetValue(", ".join(CONTENIDO))
```

or

```
self.loggerb.SetValue("\n".join(CONTENIDO))
```

or maybe you want something like

```
for RT in CONTENIDO:
    print RT
    self.loggerb.SetValue(RT)
    self.logggerb.Update() # force gui update
    wx.Sleep(1) # wait a second before going to next value
```